# React Router Redirect Issue When Clicking Links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-router

I'm encountering a problem with React Router where I have a header component and a home component, and I want to navigate to a movie detail page when a movie is clicked. The issue is that when I'm logged in, clicking any link, whether it's in the header or on the home page, always redirects me to the home page. However, when I'm not logged in, I can navigate from the home page to the detail page without any issues.
Here's My code:
App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Detail from "./components/Detail";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />}></Route>
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route path="/detail/:id" element={<Detail />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import ImgSlider from "./ImgSlider";
import Viewers from "./Viewers";
import Recommends from "./Recommend";
import NewDisney from "./NewDisney";
import Originals from "./Originals";
import Trending from "./Trending";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import db from "../firebase";
import { setMovies } from "../features/movies/movieSlice";
import { selectUserName } from "../features/user/UserSlice";

const Home = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userName = useSelector(selectUserName);

  const [recommends, setRecommends] = useState([]);
  const [newDisney, setNewDisney] = useState([]);
  const [originals, setOriginals] = useState([]);
  const [trending, setTrending] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log("hello");
    db.collection("movies").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      let recommends = [];
      let newDisney = [];
      let originals = [];
      let trending = [];

      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        const movieData = { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
        // console.log(recommends);
        switch (movieData.type) {
          default:
            recommends = [...recommends, movieData];
            break;

          case "new":
            newDisney = [...newDisney, movieData];
            break;

          case "original":
            originals = [...originals, movieData];
            break;

          case "trending":
            trending = [...trending, movieData];
            break;
        }
      });
      setRecommends(recommends);
      setNewDisney(newDisney);
      setOriginals(originals);
      setTrending(trending);

      dispatch(
        setMovies({
          recommend: recommends,
          newDisney: newDisney,
          original: originals,
          trending: trending,
        })
      );
    });
  }, [dispatch, newDisney, originals, recommends, trending, userName]);
  
  return (
    <Container>
      <ImgSlider />
      <Viewers />
      <Recommends />
      <NewDisney />
      <Originals />
      <Trending />
    </Container>
  );
};

const Container = styled.main`
  position: relative;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 250px);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: block;
  top: 72px;
  padding: 0 calc(3.5vw + 5px);

  &:after {
    background: url("/images/home-background.png") center center / cover
      no-repeat fixed;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: -1;
  }
`;

export default Home;
```

Header.js:

```
import { auth, provider } from "../firebase";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  selectUserName,
  selectUserPhoto,
  setUserLoginDetails,
  setSignOutState,
} from "../features/user/UserSlice";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

const Header = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const userName = useSelector(selectUserName);
  const userPhoto = useSelector(selectUserPhoto);
  const setUser = useCallback(
    (user) =>
      dispatch(
        setUserLoginDetails({
          name: user.displayName,
          photo: user.photoURL,
        })
      ),
    [dispatch]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        navigate("/home");
      }
    });
  }, [userName, setUser, navigate]);

  const handleAuth = () => {
    if (!userName) {
      auth
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((result) => {
          setUser(result.user);
          navigate("/home"); // After successful login, navigate to the home page
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert(error.message);
        });
    } else if (userName) {
      auth
        .signOut()
        .then(() => {
          dispatch(setSignOutState());
          navigate("/"); // After successful sign out, navigate to the login page
        })
        .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
    }
  };

  return (
    <Nav>
      <Link to="/">
        <Logo>
          <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Disney+" />
        </Logo>
      </Link>

      {!userName ? (
        <LoginBtn onClick={handleAuth}>Login</LoginBtn>
      ) : (
        <>
          <NavMenu>
            <Link to="/home">
              <img src="/images/home-icon.svg" alt="HOME" />
              <span>HOME</span>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/search">
              <img src="/images/search-icon.svg" alt="SEARCH" />
              <span>SEARCH</span>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/watchlist">
              <img src="/images/watchlist-icon.svg" alt="WATCHLIST" />
              <span>WATCHLIST</span>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/originals">
              <img src="/images/original-icon.svg" alt="ORIGINALS" />
              <span>ORIGINALS</span>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/movies">
              <img src="/images/movie-icon.svg" alt="MOVIEs" />
              <span>MOVIES</span>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/series">
              <img src="/images/series-icon.svg" alt="SERIES" />
              <span>SERIES</span>
            </Link>
          </NavMenu>
          <SignOut>
            <Link to="/">
              <USerImg src={userPhoto} alt={userName} />
              <DropDown>
                <span onClick={handleAuth}>Sign Out</span>
              </DropDown>
            </Link>
          </SignOut>
        </>
      )}
    </Nav>
  );
};

const Nav = styled.nav`
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #090b13;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 36px;
  letter-spacing: 16px;
  z-index: 3;
`;

const Logo = styled.a`
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  max-height: 70px;
  font-size: 0;
  display: inline-block;

  img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const NavMenu = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 25px;

  a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 12px;

    img {
      padding-right: 2px;
      height: 20px;
      min-width: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      z-index: auto;
    }

    span {
      color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
      font-size: 13px;
      letter-spacing: 1.42px;
      line-height: 1.08;
      padding: 2px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      position: relative;

      &:before {
        background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
        border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
        bottom: -6px;
        content: "";
        height: 2px;
        left: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        transform-origin: left center;
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) 0s;
        visibility: hidden;
        width: auto;
      }
    }

    &:hover {
      span:before {
        transform: scaleX(1);
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1 !important;
      }
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;

const LoginBtn = styled.a`
  background-color: #090b13;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;

  &:hover {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    color: #090b13;
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const USerImg = styled.img`
  height: 90%;
`;

const DropDown = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  right: 0px;
  background: rgb(19, 19, 19);
  border: 1px solid rgba(151, 151, 151, 0.34);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 50%) 0px 0px 18px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  width: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
`;

const SignOut = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  ${USerImg} {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &:hover {
    ${DropDown} {
      opacity: 1;
      transition-duration: 1s;
    }
  }
`;

export default Header;
```

Detail.js:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import db from "../firebase";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
const Detail = (props) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [detailData, setDetailData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("movies")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          setDetailData(doc.data());
        } else {
          console.log("No such document in Firebase");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error Getting documents", error);
      });
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Background>
        <img src={detailData.backgroundImg} alt={detailData.title} />
      </Background>
      <ImgTitle>
        <img
          src={detailData.titleImg}
          alt=""
        />
      </ImgTitle>
      <ContentMeta>
        <Controls>
          <Player>
            <img src="/images/play-icon-black.png" alt="" />
            <span>Play</span>
          </Player>
          <TrailerBtn>
            <img src="/images/play-icon-white.png" alt="" />
            <span>Trailer</span>
          </TrailerBtn>
          <AddList>
            <span />
            <span />
          </AddList>
          <Group>
            <div>
              <img src="/images/group-icon.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </Group>
        </Controls>
        <SubTitle>{detailData.subTitle}</SubTitle>
        <Description>{detailData.description}</Description>
      </ContentMeta>
    </Container>
  );
};

const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  min-height: calc(100vh-250px);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  top: 72px;
  padding: 0 calc(3.5vw + 5px);
`;

const Background = styled.div`
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;

  img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      width: initial;
    }
  }
`;

const ImgTitle = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 30vw;
  min-height: 170px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  width: 100%;

  img {
    max-width: 600px;
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 35vw;
  }
`;

const ContentMeta = styled.div`
  max-width: 874px;
`;

const Controls = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin: 24px 0px;
  min-height: 56px;
`;

const Player = styled.button`
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0px 22px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 24px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: 1.8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: rgb(249, 249, 249);
  border: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);

  img {
    width: 32px;
  }

  &:hover {
    background: rgb(170, 170, 170);
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0px 22px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;

    img {
      width: 25px;
    }
  }
`;

//Copying the styling from Player
const TrailerBtn = styled(Player)`
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid rgb(249, 249, 249);
  color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
`;

const AddList = styled.div`
  margin-right: 16px;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;

  span {
    background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
    display: inline-block;

    &:first-child {
      height: 2px;
      transform: translate(1px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
      width: 16px;
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      height: 16px;
      transform: translate(-8px) rotate(0deg);
      width: 2px;
    }
  }
`;

const Group = styled.div`
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;

  div {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
`;

const SubTitle = styled.div`
  color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
  font-size: 15px;
  min-height: 20px;

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
`;

const Description = styled.div`
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 16px 0px;
  color: rgb(249, 249, 249);

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
`;

export default Detail;
```

I tried to add `handleMovieClick()` inside the `Home.js` which uses `useNavigate()` to navigate to the detail page when a movie click like so

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const handleMovieClick = (movieId) => {
  // Navigate to the movie detail page when a movie is clicked
  navigate(`/detail/${movieId}`);
};
```

and then calling it isnide the call of components like so:

```
return (
    <Container>
      <ImgSlider />
      <Viewers />
      <Recommends onClick={handleMovieClick} />
      <NewDisney onClick={handleMovieClick} />
      <Originals onClick={handleMovieClick} />
      <Trending onClick={handleMovieClick} />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only odd issue I see in the code is that your `useEffect` hook in `Header` creates a new auth listener each time the component renders and the effect callback is run, and subscriptions are never cleaned up.

Return a cleanup function to unsubscribe the listener and remove the dependencies so you only instantiate one listener during the life of the component. You may also want to handle the cases where `onAuthStateChanged`'s success handler returns that the user is no longer authenticated by clearing the user state and navigating to the login route.

Example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      setUser(user);
      navigate("/home");
    } else {
      setUser(null);
      navigate("/");
    }
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Comment: Should I create a new useEffect() function or implement it in the existing one if so how should i do it

Comment: @Dhia If you are referring to the one `useEffect` in `Header` that stands up the `onAuthStateChanged` listener/callback you only need the one effect. If you are not referring to that effect then I would need a bit more context what you are asking about.

Comment: The thing is that when I log in i get redirected to the `/home` and then when i click on any other link inside `/home` i stay on there, But when im not looged in and i navigate from my local host to `/home` then i click on the links i get redirected to the desired page.

Comment: @Dhia Could you try reducing your code to a [mcve] in a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: I finally resolved it. it was in the multiple dependecies in the `useEffect` in `Header`,  specifying [userName] as the dependency array, the effect will run whenever userName changes. This prevented unnecessary re-renders and ensure that the effect runs at the appropriate times.

Comment: @Dhia Ah great! And yeah, it's why I mentioned removing all the dependencies for that effect since you really only want to instantiate the firebase auth listener once when the component mounts, and unsubscribe when it unmounts.